# Not able to find vendor-specific UUID on C# application

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to write a programm in C# which should get data from my BLE Device. Basically the programm works, my only problem is that it does not show vendor-specific UUID's. I can find the SIG-adopted services (Geberic Acess, Generic Attribute, Battery Servece,...) but i cannot find my user defined services. Does anybody know if this is a general problem on Windows C# applications?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help page. And then [edit] your question to include an [mcve] of your code that's not working

Comment: _"if this is a general problem on Windows C# applications"_ cannot confirm. What I did see is that this is a widespread issue with "Made in PRC". Like chips that _should_ have individual ids _per every single chip_ in their ROM have all the same id _per manufacturing batch_ and the like...

Comment: There are 2 possible reasons: 1. Device does not inclue such service. 2. Service protected and can be found only after pairing.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko - You are right, its reason 2. Your answer has put me on the right track. My service is protected, an therefore my application could not find it. I thought my device is paired, but it seems it is not, or not correct. After disabling the encryption i can find my service. Tanks a lot!